# why the PHP session is destroyed when page is loading multiple time?

Tags: php

I have website where I am using login and logout functionality using php.

So, for login, first I call following function :

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'happiechef_session_ids';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = false;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location:index");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id(true);    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}
```

and then I call following function to check user login information from mysql database :

```
function admin_login($email, $pass) {
    global $conn;   

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT a_email, a_pass, a_id FROM admin_profile WHERE a_email = '$email' LIMIT 1");
    $query_result =  mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $a_id = (int) $query_result['a_id']; 
    $db_hash = htmlspecialchars($query_result['a_pass']);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($num == 1) {
        if (checkbrute($email) == true) {
        // if true account is locked
            return false;
        } else {
            if(verify($pass, $db_hash)) {
                $a_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $a_id);
                $email = validate_data($email);
                $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                $_SESSION['logged_admin_user'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['logged_admin_id'] = $a_id;                
                $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $db_hash . $user_browser);
                return true;
            } else {
                $time = time();
                $query =  mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO login_attempt VALUES('', '$email', '$time')");
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }    
}
```

Well, when I refresh the page multiple time using `F5 key` from Keyboard it's automatically logged out and sometime when I visit other page it's asking me to login! Somehow it's destroyed the PHP session.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem in my code ?

Thanks In advance.

**Update :**

Here is the function to check if user is logged or not :

```
function admin_login_check() {
    // Check if all session variables are set 
    if (isset($_SESSION['logged_admin_user'], $_SESSION['logged_admin_id'], $_SESSION['login_string'])) {
        global $conn;
        $user_id = $_SESSION['logged_admin_id'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
        $username = $_SESSION['logged_admin_user'];

        // Get the user-agent string of the user.
        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        if($query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT a_pass FROM admin_profile WHERE a_email = '$username' ")) {
            $num =  mysqli_num_rows($query);
            if($num == 1) {

                $result =  mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                $password = htmlspecialchars($result['a_pass']);

                // if hash equals function is not exist    
                if(!function_exists('hash_equals')){
                    function hash_equals($str1, $str2){
                        if(strlen($str1) != strlen($str2)){
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            $res = $str1 ^ $str2;
                            $ret = 0;
                            for($i = strlen($res) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
                                $ret |= ord($res[$i]);
                            }
                            return !$ret;
                        }
                    }
                }
                $login_check = hash('sha512', $password.$user_browser); 
                if (hash_equals($login_check, $login_string) ){                    
                    return true;
                } else {          
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                 return false;
            }
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    } else {        
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: @RyanVincent I updated my question. Here you can see a function by which I can check is user is logged or not.

Comment: @RyanVincent can you tell me why the session is destroyed ?

Comment: You check the session cookie contents each time? `var_dump($_COOKIE, (isset($_SESSION['logged_admin_id']) ? $_SESSION['logged_admin_id'] : ''), __FILE__.LINE__);`? do they change when the 'session' is destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `session_regenerate_id(true)` the session should not destroyed anymore.

**Why is this happening?**
`session_regenerate_id()` replace the current session ID with a new one. The session information will be kept. When you use this function to often (reload, AJAX, etc.) you can see this effect on your session. PHP has a restriction for access to the session for only one running task. If you run `session_regenerate_id()` to often / fast the task get into queue. So the following is happening:

1. The first call changes the session ID and delete the old session (if parameter is `true`).
2. The second call has still the old session ID and tries to do some operations on it.
3. As the old session doesn't exists anymore, a new session would be created. The user is logged out now (session is invalid now).

Comment: But you know if I remove this then I have session security problem !

Comment: I updated my question with a function. Please can you check it ?

Comment: remove it and try again - problem still exists? - I search  the explanation.

Comment: Yes, If I remove it then it's does not destroyed the session.

Comment: Well, can you tell me what should I do ?